# mysqldump exclude tables does not exclude tables when using in a variable

Tags: mysql, bash

I am sure this is a simple one but struggling to understand the problem..

I am pulling table names from a file

```
# cat db.tbl.exclude
wp_users
wp_usermeta
```

and then creating a variable.

```
EXCLUDETABLE=$(while read -r tbl ; do echo --ignore-table=dbname.$tbl ; done < db.tbl.exclude | sed -e :a -e '$!N; s/\n/ /; ta')
```

Example output:

```
# echo $EXCLUDETABLE
--ignore-table=dbname.wp_users --ignore-table=dbname.wp_usermeta
```

Now if I run mysqldump...

```
mysqldump -f --routines --events --single-transaction --extended-insert "${EXCLUDETABLE}" dbname> dbname.sql
```

The tables exist in the database backup...

just to ensure the command does actually work, I used the exact output of ${EXCLUDETABLE} and tested it.

```
mysqldump -f --routines --events --single-transaction --extended-insert --ignore-table=dbname.wp_users --ignore-table=dbname.wp_usermeta dbname > dbname.sql
```

The tables exclude without issue.  Why is it problematic using a variable for these options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes around `${EXCLUDETABLE}`, as in:

```
mysqldump -f --routines --events --single-transaction --extended-insert ${EXCLUDETABLE} dbname> dbname.sql
```

If you keep the quotes, instead of seeing 4 arguments `--ignore-table=dbname.wp_users --ignore-table=dbname.wp_usermeta`, the command line will considere the concatenation of these 4 arguments as only one string that doesn't match any exspected argument.

Comment: No need to feel dumb: four eyes see better than two.